# Redirect URL by XML file

Tags: xml, redirect, xsd

i am looking for an answer how i can make url redirect with my xml file -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with PRO Sitemap Service https://pro-sitemaps.com -->

  <url>
       <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-07-08T11:16:49+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>1.0000</priority>
  </url>
```

for example i need make redirect from "https://www.example.com/" to "https://www.example.com/somepage".

I made something in XMLSchema to put another link,
specifically target link, but i dont know which type i need to put there, for example for loc link is "<xsd:element name="loc" type="tLoc"/>", but i dont know is that good move at all. So realy please, help me with that crazy XML thing :P THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

The [sitemap XML format](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) has no provision for describing redirects.

If a document has moved, put its new location in the `<loc>` element and configure your HTTP server to issue an HTTP 301 Moved Permanently (or 302 Moved Temporarily) response for the old location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response! Unfortunately i need to import all data from one XML file, cuz i am working on closed shop engine, and there is option for generate redirects from XML sitemap file. So i made an sitemap, and i need to add target link to the structure, to recive a redirect from one link, to another.